# Cronjob not working in django. The task is not performed automatically at given time

Tags: python, django, cron

I have a Django application. In that, there is an application. Within the application, I have a function py file calculate_rev and it has a function calculate_weekly. I have set cronjob in settings and added the cronjob. When `crontab -l` is executed it shows my added task. But is not running at the specified time. It runs when I do it in this way `python manage.py crontab run 3c46f4f7c6d33456f68f9796cb22ffc3`. I have added logging. When I run it manually the log is created. Otherwise, the log is not created. I am working on RedHat Linux based system

```
CRONJOBS = [
('52 09 * * 2', 'myapp.calculate_rev.calculate_weekly')
```

]

Comment: I assume you're using `django-crontab` here? What happens if you run `python manage.py crontab show`

Comment: It shows the task.

Comment: Odd, and your django application is running I assume, either via `runserver` or `gunicorn` or something? Are you running locally? Is your system time correct? (if you're in WSL this can get out of sync ...)

Comment: Don't forget to check the timezone of the app/server is correct